# How to deploy Blazor App to Ubuntu Server?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I have built a small application with .Net Core Blazor App and now I'm trying to publish it on Ubuntu server. Sadly, I could not find any specific post or guideline on this issue.

Comment: Is your Ubunu server acting as a web-server? If so, you can build your Blazor app for release and copy the files over to an accessible location.

Answer (score 0):

In order to build your Blazor application you can do the following from the directory containing the .csproj for your application:

`dotnet publish -c Release`

The command will create a set of files within your project folder. The names of the directory may differ slightly depending on the verion of dotnet your are using.

`bin/Release/netstandard2.0/publish/project-name/dist/`

You can then copy the contents of the dist folder to a location on your server accessible to the webserver. When index.html is loaded, your Blazor application will then execute.

[More information on building for release can be found at this link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was wondering if you have full steps on how to host the app on Ubuntu?